# RDLC report C#. Show or hide controls thru conditioning

Tags: c#, rdlc

I'm new at using reporting tool and i can't figure out how to show/hide image in report. This is my code. Been playing with it for a while and I can't get right solution. ***Suppose i'm gonna hide it***.

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.IIf(First(Fields![ES_EXCUSETYPE].Value, "DataSet1") = "1", True, False)
```

Answer (score 1):

As you already know you have to set `Hidden` property of your `Image` using this syntax:

```
=IIf(<condition for hiding an object>, True, False)
```

If your `Image` is inside a `Table` detail you can use this syntax:

```
=IIf(Fields![ES_EXCUSETYPE].Value = "1", True, False)
```

If your `Image` is outside a `Table` detail you could use this syntax:

```
=IIf(First(Fields![ES_EXCUSETYPE].Value, "DataSet1") = "1", True, False)
```

That syntax only verify if the first record in `Dataset` meets the condition; so it is usually better to use a `ReportParameter` instead.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: The error was only the data type, i forgot that i set the value to INT and only converting it to string at the back end so i change "1" ----> 1 and fortunately it work :)

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.IIf(First(Fields![ES_EXCUSETYPE].Value, "DataSet1") = 1, True, False)
```